# Jenkins inbound agent is run as root user

Tags: jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-agent

I have defined a node in the jenkins cloud config with the following docker file, everything is fine, except when I run a job it runs as root user.

```
FROM jenkins/inbound-agent:alpine as jnlp

FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11

ARG DOCKER_VERSION=18.03.0-ce
ARG DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION=1.21.0
ARG USER=jenkins

USER root

COPY --from=jnlp /usr/local/bin/jenkins-agent /usr/local/bin/jenkins-agent
COPY --from=jnlp /usr/share/jenkins/agent.jar /usr/share/jenkins/agent.jar

RUN apt-get install ca-certificates wget -y \
    && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives \
    && wget https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.19.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl -q -O /usr/local/bin/kubectl \
    && chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/kubectl

RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/`uname -m`/docker-$DOCKER_VERSION.tgz | tar --strip-components=1 -xz -C /usr/local/bin docker/docker
RUN curl -fsSL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/$DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

RUN touch /debug-flag

RUN useradd jenkins

USER jenkins

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/jenkins-agent"]
```

When my job start, the user is root. And I need to run with a non root user to some jobs, my shared library on jenkins work well.
The only problem that I have is when I run some test on some projects with a database embedded, due to it needs to run in a non root user.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Pod Template and Container Template to see if you set the "runAsUser" and "runAsGroup". You can set to 1000 as default "jenkins" user uid and gid.